# Pythonic way to print a chess board in console

Tags: python, dictionary, chess

I was wondering what would be the best pythonic way to print a console chess board using a dictionary.

Should I use list ? but what happens if their is no piece on the board on a certain row?

Edit :
[image: Exemple]

Comment: What does a console chess board look like?

Comment: something like that http://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/conchess/screenshots/102810.jpg

Comment: It would be helpful to see your dictionary. reindeer's answer is exactly right that nested lists would be a better data structure for this, but a fuller answer depends slightly on how you currently represent *pieces*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In chess programs (typically for computing best moves, solve riddles, etc.) internally a 10×10 board is used where the middle 8×8 fields are used by the visible and playable board.  (The margin helps keep the code simple.)  To simplify memory management, typically a linear memory is used to store this, i. e. 100 fields.  The position of a field of the board is then computed using `board[(y+1) * 10 + (x+1)]` with x, y in the range 0..7.  (Init by `board = [ 0 ] * 100`.)

So you might want to use this, just in case your program later should expand to also compute moves or stay compatible with a library doing this.

As for graphics, I propose to use this board:

```
     A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 | @___@ |  %~b  |  .@.  | \o*o/ | __+__ |  .@.  |  %~b  | @___@ |
8|  @@@  | `'dX  |  @@@  |  @@@  | `@@@' |  @@@  | `'dX  |  @@@  |8
 | d@@@b |  d@@b | ./A\. | d@@@b | d@@@b | ./A\. |  d@@b | d@@@b |
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |
7|  (@)  |  (@)  |  (@)  |  (@)  |  (@)  |  (@)  |  (@)  |  (@)  |7
 |  d@b  |  d@b  |  d@b  |  d@b  |  d@b  |  d@b  |  d@b  |  d@b  |
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |
6|       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |6
 |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       |
5| . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       |5
 | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       |
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |
4|       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |4
 |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       |
3| . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       |3
 | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       | . . . |       |
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |   _   |
2|  ( )  |  ( )  |  ( )  |  ( )  |  ( )  |  ( )  |  ( )  |  ( )  |2
 |  /_\  |  /_\  |  /_\  |  /_\  |  /_\  |  /_\  |  /_\  |  /_\  |
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
 | [___] |  %~\  |  .O.  | \o^o/ | __+__ |  .O.  |  %~\  | [___] |
1|  [ ]  | `')(  |  \ /  |  [ ]  | `. .' |  \ /  | `')(  |  [ ]  |1
 | /___\ |  <__> |  /_\  | /___\ | /___\ |  /_\  |  <__> | /___\ |
  ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
     A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H
```

I made these ASCII graphics back in the 90s for [Tubmud](http://www.tubmud.de).  Feel free to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip the 10x10 board is a great idea thanks for sharing!

Comment: HAHAHAHA no waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay that board is aaaaaaawsome! I would like to put a plus 175 for that :D

Comment: @DamianLattenero Actually, you can put a bounty on the question and reward me the points ;-)  — Just kidding ;-)

Comment: @Alfe maybe some day ;) haha

Answer (score 2):

I would use a nested list for that problem. In chess, you have an 8x8 grid, which can easily built by python list comprehension magic.

grid = [ [" "] * 8 for unused in range(8)]

You than can access and alter the elements by indexing an array:

```
grid[0][0] = 'T'
```

You can use lower case letters for white and upper case letters for black figures, and their first letter or so for the kind, like 'Q' for black queen.

Dictionary looks not good for me, since it is hard to make operations for checking valid moves or sth, because you have no other way to determine the position of a figure by iterating over all values. The grid is most natural.

Comment: Beware of assigning things to a `list` that has been multiplied; it will use the same instance and thus put `'T'` on an entire row.

Comment: @akaIDIOT although note that this problem *is* avoided by reindeer's answer - the only thing being shallow copied here are (immutable) strings.

Comment: I can tell you that I tried it before, and it has only one 'T'.

Comment: @lvc ah, it seems you're right, sorry. Been bitten by this so many times I automatically flinch...

Comment: +1 for the nested lists, which are almost certainly better than a dictionary for all the reasons you mention. However, I can't necessarily agree with using strings (or these specific strings) for pieces - rather, use *whatever the OP already uses* (which we don't know). If that happens to be a class (which could, eg, also know that piece's move semantics), then `None` or a special 'null' piece might be a better representation of an empty square than `' '`. Also, you don't answer the question of *how to print this* - you would probably play with `join` and a genexp.

Comment: I would print it with
print(grid)
since python already does it pretty nice.
Other ways are a nested for loop, maybe enumerated to get the grid coordinates right.